How can I access YouTube watch history with API
English is not my native language so I’m sorry for any grammar mistakes.
In general, I’m making school project with my friends. We want to make an app which will count how many Shorts/TikToks have you watched through whole day.
It is mostly done but the most important part is not working - accessing YouTube watch history. From what I found on the Internet it is not accessible by YouTube API for a couple of years. So the question is how can we get it?
I will be very thankful for every answer.

As far as I know there is no API for this purpose. You can only web-scrape https://www.youtube.com/feed/history.
